# Porting Python on Windows using pywin32/excel to Linux on Vagrant Machine

Tags: python, linux, excel, vagrant, pywin32

I have written an extensive python package that utilizes excel and pywin32.
I am now in the progress of moving this package to a linux environment on a Vagrant machine.

I know there are "emulator-esque" software packages (e.g. WINE) that can run Windows applications and look-a-likes for some Windows applications (e.g. Excel to OpenOffice).
However, I am not seeing the right path to take in order to get my pywin32/Excel dependent code written for Windows running in a Linux environment on a Vagrant machine.  Ideally, I would not have to alter my code at all and just do the appropriate installs on my Vagrant machine.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is, you can't. WINE does not expose a bottled Windows environment's COM registry out to linux—and, even if it did, `pywin32` doesn't build on anything but Windows.

So, here are some options, roughly ordered from the least amount of change to your code and setup to the most:

- Run both your Python script and Excel under real Windows, inside a real emulator.
- Run both your Python script and Excel under WINE.
- Write or find a library that does expose a bottled Windows environment's COM registry out to Linux.
- Write or find a cross-platform DCOM library that presents a `win32com`-like API, then change your code to use that to connect to the bottled Excel remotely.
- Rewrite your code to script Excel indirectly by, e.g., `ssh`ing into a Windows box and running minimal WSH scripts.
- Rewrite your code to script `LibreOffice` or whatever you prefer instead of Excel.
- Rewrite your code to process Excel files (or CSV or some other interchange format) directly instead of scripting Excel.